# How can I extract part of an element, and reuse this (numerical) value in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, random

Ok, so the background to what I would like to do overall is 'randomly select a car from the list of results'.

So far, what I've successfully done is randomly select a Car type from a simple list of possibilities.

```
var cartype = ['small-city', 'hatchback', 'saloon', 'estate', '4x4']
var selectedtype = cartype[Math.floor(Math.random() * cartype.length)]
```

What I'm also able to do is randomly select a resulting page from a static value (in this case, any page between 1 and 10);

```
var cfspageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1
```

I can then load the random page and it all works Ok

```
.url(`https://www.parkers.co.uk/cars-for-sale/type-${selectedtype}/?page=${cfspageNumber}`)
```

Upon loading the landing page of the resulting list of cars for sale with the (randomly) selected Car type, what I'd then like to do is randomly select a page so that (in theory) a different list of cars is displayed each time the test is run.

So, in the case below, I would like to randomly select any of the 1882 pages and load that page.

[image]

If the number of pages was always 1882, I'd be Ok as I can randomly select from a 'static' list.

However, depending on what Car type is randomly selected beforehand, the number of pages changes.

What I would like to do, is somehow 'extract' this value (in this case 1882 but is dynamic), and then use this value to randomly select a page.

```
var cfspageNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1882, or whatever is listed as the final page) + 1
```

Comment: You seem to know the total number of results found, and the number of results shown per page.  Should be enough info?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the a Element and use .innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
var extractedString = document.querySelector(".results-paging__pages__number a").innerHTML;
var numberOfPages = parseInt(extractedString);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Alexandre, much appreciated. I'm currently getting **'NaN'** outputted, so I'm going to have a read of some .innerHTML documentation and see what I can do to rectify this.

Comment: Ok, so I'm still struggling to extract the numerical value for this. I'm still getting the NaN error, so wondering if I'm extracting the wrong part (i.e. not the numerical value) of the element?